# Angular 2 - routing between two bootstrapped components

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-routing

I have two components that are bootstrapped separately because they cannot share a parent selector. Is it possible to route between them? I am specifically thinking of pagination.

Comment: What does "route between them" mean?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, bootstrapping creates the Angular2 application, and you can't route between two separate applications.